# How To count number of employees with a specfic criteria of child node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am trying to count how many employees in the below xml has operation != NONE and pi:Code_Name = ESPP Base Salary . Ideally the answer should be 1.

I am wondering how this can be achieved. I am using Oxygen as the XSLT writer.

```
XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof">
    <pi:PayGroup>
        <pi:Employee>
            <pi:Summary>
                <pi:Employee_ID>2350</pi:Employee_ID>
                <pi:Name>Delvin Jay ABAN</pi:Name>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>United States External Pay Entity</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>United States Pay Group - Semi-Monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>true</pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>
            </pi:Summary>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">Overtime</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">E002</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20140701</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount pi:PriorValue="">193.96</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount pi:PriorValue="">193.96</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">Base Salary</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">E790</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20140701</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount pi:PriorValue="">193.96</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount pi:PriorValue="">193.96</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Additional_Information>
                <pi:EffDateStockForm>2015-03-01</pi:EffDateStockForm>
                <pi:CNUM pi:PriorValue="123U87">135632</pi:CNUM>
            </pi:Additional_Information>
        </pi:Employee>
        <pi:Employee>
            <pi:Summary>
                <pi:Employee_ID>4471</pi:Employee_ID>
                <pi:Name>Vergel LIRIO</pi:Name>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>United States External Pay Entity</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>United States Pay Group - Semi-Monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>false</pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>
            </pi:Summary>
            <pi:Personal>
                <pi:First_Name>Vergel</pi:First_Name>
                <pi:Last_Name>LIRIO</pi:Last_Name>
            </pi:Personal>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">Base Salary</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">E790</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20151001</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount pi:PriorValue="">25000</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount pi:PriorValue="">25000</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Payment_Election>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Payment_Type>DIRECT DEPOSIT</pi:Payment_Type>
                <pi:Country>PH</pi:Country>
                <pi:Bank_Account_Name>VERGEL LIRIO</pi:Bank_Account_Name>
                <pi:Account_Number>4339169263</pi:Account_Number>
                <pi:Account_Type>SA</pi:Account_Type>
                <pi:Bank_Name>BANK OF P.I.</pi:Bank_Name>
                <pi:Bank_ID_Number>40398</pi:Bank_ID_Number>
            </pi:Payment_Election>
            <pi:Additional_Information>
                <pi:EffDateStockForm>2015-03-01</pi:EffDateStockForm>
                <pi:CNUM pi:PriorValue="X91664">123456</pi:CNUM>
            </pi:Additional_Information>
        </pi:Employee>
        <pi:Employee>
            <pi:Summary>
                <pi:Employee_ID>21365</pi:Employee_ID>
                <pi:Name>Ava Waterbury</pi:Name>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>United States External Pay Entity</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>United States Pay Group - Semi-Monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>false</pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>
            </pi:Summary>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">Overtime</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">E002</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20150731</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount pi:PriorValue="">12000</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount pi:PriorValue="">12000</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name>Base Salary</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code>E790</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction>E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date>20150731</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount>12000</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount>12000</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">ESPP Base Salary</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">ESPP_BaseSalary</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">D</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20150901</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Percentage pi:PriorValue="">0.02</pi:Percentage>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">ESPP Non Sales</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">ESPP_NonSales</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">D</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20150901</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Percentage pi:PriorValue="">0.03</pi:Percentage>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Additional_Information>
                <pi:CNUM>042227</pi:CNUM>
            </pi:Additional_Information>
        </pi:Employee>
        <pi:Employee>
            <pi:Summary>
                <pi:Employee_ID>21951</pi:Employee_ID>
                <pi:Name>Hollie Hoffler</pi:Name>
                <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>United States External Pay Entity</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
                <pi:Pay_Group_Name>United States Pay Group - Semi-Monthly</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
                <pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>false</pi:Contain_Corrections_or_Rescinds>
            </pi:Summary>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name pi:PriorValue="">Overtime</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code pi:PriorValue="">E002</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction pi:PriorValue="">E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date pi:PriorValue="">20150521</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount pi:PriorValue="">4153.2</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount pi:PriorValue="">4153.2</pi:Prorated_Amount>

            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Earnings_Deductions>
                <pi:Operation>NONE</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Code_Name>Base Salary</pi:Code_Name>
                <pi:Code>E790</pi:Code>
                <pi:Earning_or_Deduction>E</pi:Earning_or_Deduction>
                <pi:Start_Date>20150521</pi:Start_Date>
                <pi:Amount>4153.2</pi:Amount>
                <pi:Prorated_Amount>4153.2</pi:Prorated_Amount>
            </pi:Earnings_Deductions>
            <pi:Payment_Election>
                <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
                <pi:Payment_Type pi:PriorValue="">DIRECT DEPOSIT</pi:Payment_Type>
                <pi:Country pi:PriorValue="">US</pi:Country>
                <pi:Account_Number pi:PriorValue="">890test</pi:Account_Number>
                <pi:Account_Type pi:PriorValue="">DDA</pi:Account_Type>
                <pi:Bank_Name pi:PriorValue="">1st Merit</pi:Bank_Name>
                <pi:Bank_ID_Number pi:PriorValue="">041200555</pi:Bank_ID_Number>
            </pi:Payment_Election>
            <pi:Additional_Information>
                <pi:EffDateStockForm pi:PriorValue="">2015-09-09</pi:EffDateStockForm>
                <pi:CNUM>0A8737</pi:CNUM>
            </pi:Additional_Information>
        </pi:Employee>

    </pi:PayGroup>
</pi:Payroll_Extract_Employees>
```

Comment: Well, `count(//foo)` counts the `foo` elements, and a predicate in square brackets filters a node set, e.g. `count(//foo[bar = 'whatever' and not(baz = 'whatelse')])` counts only the `foo` element where there is a `bar` child with string value `whatever` and where there is no `baz` element with value `whatelse`. So try to put your condition into a predicate and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath:

`Earnings_Deductions`-elements having both Operation != 'NONE' and Code_Name = 'ESPP Base Salary':

```
//pi:Earnings_Deductions[pi:Operation != 'NONE' and
                         pi:Code_Name = 'ESPP Base Salary']
```

`Employee`-elements having `Earnings_Deductions` matching this:

```
//pi:Employee[pi:Earnings_Deductions[pi:Operation != 'NONE' and
                                     pi:Code_Name = 'ESPP Base Salary']])
```

Counting these employees:

```
count(//pi:Employee[
           pi:Earnings_Deductions[pi:Operation != 'NONE' and
                                  pi:Code_Name = 'ESPP Base Salary']
                   ]
      )
```